# Can Zune playlists be created on the device?

Tags: zune, zune-player

I see that I can add songs to "Now Playing" but is there a way to save this as a playlist, or create and save a playlist on the phone without using the Zune application on the PC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Here are the steps.

1. Long press any song and tap `add to now playing`. You can keep doing this till all the songs you need in the playlist are added to the now playing list. When doing this, the songs added to now playing list will be played.
2. Use the volume hardware button to bring up the name of the song being played at the top of the screen, below the volume indicator.
3. Tap the song name. It'll take you to the `now playing` section of the music + video hub.
4. Tap the name of the song under the album art.
5. The list of songs you've added to the now playing list will show up. There will be a save button at the bottom of this list that will allow you to create a playlist from all the songs in the `now playing` list.

And here's a [link](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/music/create-a-playlist.aspx) from the windows phone help docs with the steps.

Comment: Sweet, thanks, read the manual right? :)  I guess I just missed that.  Next step I'll see if these sync back to Zune desktop.